# How to apply button press-latency in an android app?

Tags: java, android

I am building an audio recorder app, and i used the onTouch method to capture sound, then it plays back the captured sound automatically. There are two issues:

First, the app fails to record the last few bits of your input if you immediately stop touching the button, so you have to record your audio and then await silent for around 2 seconds before you move your finger, and the app will record the full audio minus the last silent bits.

Second, if user taps or mushes the touch-button, the app crashes.

By somehow adding button-tapping latency (button remains pressed for a specified amound of seconds after the user had withdrawn their finger), both these issues will be resolved.

Here is the code:

```
        mRecordBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                if ((motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)) {
                    startRecording();
                    mRecordLabel.setText("Recording...");
                }
                else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    stopRecording();
                    mRecordLabel.setText("Recording Stopped...");

                    MediaPlayer soundPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(fileName));
                    soundPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    soundPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                       try {
                          soundPlayer.setDataSource(fileName);
                          soundPlayer.prepare();
                        }
                         catch (IOException e){
                             e.printStackTrace();
                          }

                        soundPlayer.start();

                    mRecordLabel.setText("Do it again!");
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Recording methods:

```
    private void startRecording() {
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        recorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }
        recorder.start();
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;
    }
```

Comment: can you share stop recording and start recording codes too?

Comment: Coming right up.